# php- XML import with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, database, import, simplexml

I want to setup a script to import an XML file in my DB.
My problem is, that I don't know how I should write the import on a smart way, so that the PHP script identifies each child information.
Can anyone help me?

```
<books>
   <book attribute="123" attribute2="12345">
    <basic_information>
        <name addition="fooobar">fooobar</name>
        <book_genre>
            <genre>Action</genre>
            <genre>Thriller</genre>
        </book_genre>
        <languages>
            <language>Deutsch</language>
            <language>Englisch</language>
            <language>Polnisch</language>
            <language>Russisch</language>
        </languages>
    </basic_information>
    <author_information>
        <name addition="fooabr">Mr_Ed</name>
    </author_information>
</book>
<book attribute="123" attribute2="12345">
    <basic_information>
        <name addition="fooobar">fooobar</name>

        <genres>
            <genre>Action</genre>
            <genre>Thriller</genre>
        </genres>
        <languages>
            <language>Deutsch</language>
            <language>Englisch</language>
            <language>Polnisch</language>
            <language>Russisch</language>
        </languages>
    </basic_information>
    <author_information>
        <name addition="fooabr">Mr_Ed</name>
    </author_information>
</book>
```

Comment: `<genre1>Action</genre1><genre2>Thriller</genre2>` Serious?!? Who numbers elements in this way in XML?

Comment: its just a sample, sorry for this. I change it

Comment: I have no idea how to open each element and import or display it

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Your problem is two folded here. You should also provide the structure of your database here. Otherwise I highly suggest you take a database that is XML based. Such databases do exist. Also here is a similar question which might give you some ideas: [Get XML tags from asXML()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31187575/367456)

Answer (score 2):

Even though each XML file on it's own could  represent a database, there are most often two fundamental differences between XML and relational SQL databases.

The most obvious one is the *schema*. The XML you present in your question has *no schema at all*. An SQL database by definition has a schema.

Not only does your XML has no schema, you also even don't share anything about it's meaning. So the smartest would be to totally neglect any schema here.

So to give you *one* example how the XML from your question then could be turned into a database table. You could create a database table that consists of two columns: *Path* and *Value*. You then could decide to put in there all attributes and leaf-text-nodes:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|path                                                         |value   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/@attribute                                    |123     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/@attribute2                                   |12345   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/name/@addition              |fooobar |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/name/text()                 |fooobar |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/book_genre/genre[1]/text()  |Action  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/book_genre/genre[2]/text()  |Thriller|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/languages/language[1]/text()|Deutsch |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/languages/language[2]/text()|Englisch|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/languages/language[3]/text()|Polnisch|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/languages/language[4]/text()|Russisch|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/author_information/name/@addition             |fooabr  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/author_information/name/text()                |Mr_Ed   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/@attribute                                    |123     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/@attribute2                                   |12345   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/name/@addition              |fooobar |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/name/text()                 |fooobar |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/genres/genre[1]/text()      |Action  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/genres/genre[2]/text()      |Thriller|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/languages/language[1]/text()|Deutsch |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/languages/language[2]/text()|Englisch|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/languages/language[3]/text()|Polnisch|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/basic_information/languages/language[4]/text()|Russisch|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/author_information/name/@addition             |fooabr  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[2]/author_information/name/text()                |Mr_Ed   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Creating such conversions is pretty straight forward with an XML parser that supports Xpath queries like [the dom extension in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php):

```
$doc    = new DOMDocument();
$result = $doc->loadXML($buffer);
if (!$result) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('Could not load XML');
}
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$nodes = $xpath->query('(//@*|(.|.//*)[not(*)]/text())');

$table = [['path', 'value']];

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    /** @var DOMNode $node */
    $path    = $node->getNodePath();
    $value   = $node->nodeValue;
    $table[] = [$path, $value];
}

echo new TextTable($table);
```

But such data is yet little normalized. Obviously there are duplicate values. They seem as an easy first target to gain more normalization. For example with a store that keeps track of value identities:

```
$values = new IdentityStore('value');
$table = [['path', $values->getKey()]];

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    /** @var DOMNode $node */
    $path  = $node->getNodePath();
    $value = $values->add($node->nodeValue);

    $table[] = [$path, $value];
}

echo new TextTable($table);
echo new TextTable($values);
```

This then changes the values to their IDs:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|path                                                         |value_id|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/@attribute                                    |1       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/@attribute2                                   |2       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/name/@addition              |3       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/name/text()                 |3       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|/books/book[1]/basic_information/book_genre/genre[1]/text()  |4       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
...
```

And giving the values their own table:

```
+--------+--------+
|value_id|value   |
+--------+--------+
|1       |123     |
+--------+--------+
|2       |12345   |
+--------+--------+
|3       |fooobar |
+--------+--------+
|4       |Action  |
+--------+--------+
|5       |Thriller|
+--------+--------+
|6       |Deutsch |
+--------+--------+
|7       |Englisch|
+--------+--------+
|8       |Polnisch|
+--------+--------+
|9       |Russisch|
+--------+--------+
|10      |fooabr  |
+--------+--------+
|11      |Mr_Ed   |
+--------+--------+
```

This on it's own doesn't look much helpful. Even now the values are normalized, it's perhaps more interesting on how to map the paths instead of the values.

The paths have the table names encoded. Each square bracket denotes a recordset within a table represented by the path before it. If that table is within another recordset of a prefixed table, then this construes a relation.

So that could be an interesting approach as well:

```
$tables = new PathTables();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    /** @var DOMNode $node */
    $path = $node->getNodePath();
    $tables->add($path, $node->nodeValue);
}
echo $tables;
```

But then, the values aren't de-normalized and it's known to the schema, whether or not to group values. Take note on the values that are comma-separated values to notice the shortcomings:

```
===  books_book  ===

+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|book_id|@attribute|@attribute2|basic_information/name/@addition|basic_information/name/text()|basic_information_book_genre_genre.genre_id|basic_information_languages_language.language_id|author_information/name/@addition|author_information/name/text()|basic_information_genres_genre.genre_id|
+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|1      |123       |12345      |fooobar                         |fooobar                      |1,2                                        |1,2,3,4                                         |fooabr                           |Mr_Ed                         |                                       |
+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|2      |123       |12345      |fooobar                         |fooobar                      |                                           |1,2,3,4                                         |fooabr                           |Mr_Ed                         |1,2                                    |
+-------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+

===  basic_information_book_genre_genre  ===

+--------+--------+
|genre_id|text()  |
+--------+--------+
|1       |Action  |
+--------+--------+
|2       |Thriller|
+--------+--------+

===  basic_information_languages_language  ===

+-----------+-----------------+
|language_id|text()           |
+-----------+-----------------+
|1          |Deutsch,Deutsch  |
+-----------+-----------------+
|2          |Englisch,Englisch|
+-----------+-----------------+
|3          |Polnisch,Polnisch|
+-----------+-----------------+
|4          |Russisch,Russisch|
+-----------+-----------------+

===  basic_information_genres_genre  ===

+--------+--------+
|genre_id|text()  |
+--------+--------+
|1       |Action  |
+--------+--------+
|2       |Thriller|
+--------+--------+
```

So in any case you're running into the problem that you have a missing schema. With a schema for both the XML document and the SQL database, you could easily map between the two with xpath expressions defining the mappings.

But without, it's overly complicated. A change in the XML will change your SQL's schema. Conversion errors will likely go unnoticed, so the only straight forward method would be a mapping of xpath-paths to values.

For sure it would be interesting on how to further normalize in a useful manner, but I'd say that's more for a computer class than a Q&A site. Find two further resources, one focussing on database technology and one about mapping XML into SQL structures while streaming:

- [Storing XML in Relational Databases](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/803) (Jun 2001; by Igor Dayen)
- [Supporting Efficient Streaming and Insertion of XML
  Data in RDBMS](http://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~boehme/paper/Boehme_DLN_DIWeb_CR.pdf)  (Apr 2004; by Timo Böhme, Erhard Rahm)

Answer (score -1):

Once the XML data is opened, each element is loaded via the format `string->fieldname`.

Try this:

```
$books = simplexml_load_file("xmlfile.xml");

foreach($books->books->book as $book){

    $attribute = $book["@attributes"]["attribute"]; //123
    $attribute2 = $book["@attributes"]["attribute2"]; //12345
    $name = $book->basic_information->name; //fooobar
    $name_addition = $book->basic_information->name["@attributes"]["addition"]; //fooobar
    $genres = $book->basic_information->book_genre; //array; $genres[0] = "Action" etc
    $languages = $book->basic_information->languages; //array; $languages[0] = "Deutsch" etc
    $author = $book->author_information->name; //"Mr_Ed"
    $author_addition = $book->author_information->name["@attributes"]["addition"]; //fooabr

    //...
}
```