# php: how to make dynamic table?

Tags: php

I have a question, I want to have a dynamic table in php without database. The number of rows and columns in the table should be easy to adjust.
I want to make a variable of the rows and columns.

How can I make this? Is here a tutorial about?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number of ways to store your data. If you choose not to use a database then saving the data to file after encoding it would probably the next most common way.

Take a look at the XML example I've included here, let me know if you have any more questions. There is definitely more than one way you can do this.
[PHP XML to dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997835/php-xml-to-dynamic-table)